# Javascript: Selecting photo using showOpenFilePicker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, file

I am accessing the user selected photo using showOpenFilePicker. but after selecting the photo, the input file data is null. It looks like he didn't. so I'm trying to manually add the user selected photo to the input file element. but still it doesn't happen. what should I do?

html:

```
 <div class="col-md-3 iniTpe">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="researchPhoto">Example file input</label>
                <input name="researchPhoto" onclick="Research.OpenFiles(event)" type="file" accept="image/*" class="form-control-file" id="researchPhoto">
            </div>
 </div>
```

javascript:

```
OpenFiles: async function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let files = await window.showOpenFilePicker({
        types: [
            {
                description: 'İmage Files',
                accept: {
                    'image/*': ['.png', '.gif', '.jpeg', '.jpg'],
                },
            },
        ],
        excludeAcceptAllOption: true,
        multiple: false,
    });
  
    let fileData = await files[0].getFile();

 

    document.getElementById("researchPhoto").files[0] = fileData;


    console.log(document.getElementById("researchPhoto").files[0])//comes null. normally it should not be null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need one additional step after `.getFile()`. Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) `getFile` returns a blob. You probably want to use a method like `.text()` to get the text of the file or another function mentioned on in the documentation such as `createBitmapImage()` to process the file as an image.

Comment: When the user selects the photo and clicks the button, I want to save the photo to the database. but after selecting the photo, it returns null as if you didn't select it. So what exactly do I need to do now?

Comment: What's the value of fileData before you attach it to the researchPhoto element and then retrieve it. It could be that storing a blob on an HTML element isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL_static) and then create the image:

```
// Create image
var url = URL.createObjectURL(fileData)
var img = new Image();
img.src = url;

img.onload = function() {
    // Do something
}
```